# Visual Studio C# auto new lines

Tags: c#

When writing lines to console, compiler automatically adds new lines, I mean:

```
using System;

class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
            bool bulas = i % 3 == 0;
            if ( bulas )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Boolas, {0}", bulas);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output of this is:

```
0
Boolas, True
1
2
3
Boolas, True
4
5
6
Boolas, True
7
8
9
Boolas, True
```

What do I have to do if I want to have everything in one line?

Comment: Not using the `Write` method will get you wrong result. :-)

Comment: terrible name for this question as it has nothing to do with Visual studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, don't use `Console.WriteLine` but [Console.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) instead.

[Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) inserts a [System.Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Comment: LOL! When I think about it, it looks so stupid... And I've been writing Write and WriteLns in pascal for about two years and it didn't come to my head... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the compiler who adds the new lines, but the [WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) method. WriteLine() writes whatever you pass *plus a new line*.

Use the [Write()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) method instead to write stuff to the console without an extra new line.

Comment: To be fair... in the end, it's the compiler that reads `writeline` and writes the IL that does a carriage return, but I know what you mean.